# How should I configure ASP.NET Web API 2 for OWIN in IIS?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm finding more and more packages for ASP.NET are being offered as OWIN middleware. In some cases there's both an OWIN version and "traditional" version, in some cases there's only the OWIN option. This has led to my ASP.NET Web API application using two different "startup" configuration styles. The traditional configuration for ASP.NET Web API, and OWIN for everything else. I want to consolidate on the OWIN configuration style, but how should I be configuring ASP.NET Web API 2 for hosting in IIS using OWIN?

Everything I read about using OWIN for ASP.NET Web API 2 references the `IAppBuilder` extension method `UseWebApi(HttpConfiguration configuration)`. But that extension method is in the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost` [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost/). It appears I can use that package in an IIS host and move away from using `System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration`, but the name "Self Host" is leaving me with doubts.

Is this a recognised approach? Are there gotchas I should know of? Why does the default "File > New Project" in VS2015 *not* take this approach for Web API configuration, while it *does* use OWIN configuration for authentication middleware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IAppBuilder` extension method `UseWebApi(HttpConfiguration configuration)` is in the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin` package not in the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost`

Comment: You're right, I don't know how I ever missed this. Even going back to the 5.0 versions released on 17/10/2013, that's the case. I also see that the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost` package doesn't even include any assemblies, only references to other packages.